# Differences between the standard and extended versions of TWD S6 E16

Tags: the-walking-dead, alternate-version

Season 6 of The Walking Dead was finally released on DVD and Blu-ray. Among the special features is an extended version of episode 16:

> ...executive producers Robert Kirkman, Scott M. Gimple and Greg
>   Nicotero told EW previously that they shot Negan’s entrance two-ways,
>   with a more profanity-laced version planned for the Blu-ray set, so
>   you can expect to see that included.

<sup>Source: [The Walking Dead: Extended version of season 6 finale to be released on Blu-ray](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/06/21/walking-dead-blu-ray-season-6-finale-extended-version)</sup>

Having looked briefly (read: did not watch end to end, taking notes) at both versions on the Blu-rays, I can confirm that Negan drops quite a few F-bombs in the extended version while the standard version has much less profanity (just a few choice words).

However, there appears to be more differences than that: viewing the two versions, scenes do not occur at the same times. Some of them are off by 20-30 seconds, leading me to believe there is more material added to the extended edition earlier in the episode (note: the extended edition is only around a minute longer).

What differences other than Negan's profanity, if any, are there between the two versions of The Walking Dead season 6 episode 16? Are any of these differences important enough to add any meaningful information to the story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few scenes with differing lengths (marked with TV Version time / Extended Version time):

> **30:37 / 30:37-31:44:**
>
> After the attack in the woods and the black screen due to a commercial
>   break, the Extended Version contains an additional scene with Morgan.
>   He is riding across the ghost town for a while and the sound of bells
>   is audible in the background.
>
> *Extended version is 66.7 sec longer*
>
> **53:44-53:59 / 54:51-55:05**
>
> Alternate take. Negan swears plus his voice is pitched differently:
>   "You killed more of my people. Not cool. Not fucking cool. You have no
>   fucking idea how not fucking cool that shit is."
>
> *TV Version is 0.8 sec longer*
>
> **55:28-55:39 / 56:34-56:45**
>
> After quite some time without any alteration whatsoever, alternate
>   footage has been used here.
>
> Negan: "But swallow it you most certainly motherfucking will. You
>   ruled the roost."
>
> *Extended Version is 0.4 sec longer*
>
> **55:56-56:10 / 57:02-57:16**
>
> Negan: "You are not safe. Not even fucking close. In fact, you are
>   fucked (pegged), more fucked (pegged) if you don't give me (do) what I
>   want. And what I want is half your shit."
>
> *TV Version 0.3 sec longer*
>
> **56:33-56:45 / 57:39-57:48**
>
> When Negan keeps talking, the TV Version sticks to the medium long
>   shot for a little while. After that, an alternate take follows.
>
> Negan: "We own that fucking door. You try to fucking stop us (and) we
>   will fucking knock that fucker (it) down."
>
> *TV Version is 2.8 sec longer*
>
> **57:11-57:25 / 58:14-58:30**
>
> Negan: "I want you to work for me. And You can't do that if you're
>   fucking dead, now, can you? I'm not growing a garden."
>
> *Extended Version is 1.7 sec longer*
>
> **57:32-57:38 / 58:37-58:47**
>
> ...and he ends his comment with "lot of them" - the shot is the same. 
>   The Blu-ray on the other hand contains a closer shot of Negan and in
>   addition to that, he uses the words "shitload of them" instead.  After
>   that, an alternate take with a slightly longer comment: "More than I'm
>   comfortable with. And for that, well for that you're gonna fucking
>   pay."
>
> *Extended Version is 3.9 sec longer*
>
> **57:44-57:58 / 58:53-59:06**
>
> After a few identical reaction shots, more alternate takes follow. Of
>   course, Negan's choice of words is also different: "I'm gonna beat the
>   holy fuck-fucking-fuckedy-fuck (hell) outta one of you."
>
> *TV Version is 0.4 sec longer*

Aside from that, there are a few scenes with different audio due to language, but those are the scenes which have actual differences in length.

**Source:** http://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=596638

Answer (score -2):

Might be too late but here you go. Hers a full list of the added scenes:

http://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=596638

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Please sum up the various differences in your answer.

Comment: There is some good info in that link, but please read **[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/)**